# To increase number of mappers while querying in hive

Tags: hiveql

I want to run my hive query with 1500 mappers. I have set reducers to 500. To what value should i set input splitsize inorder to achieve the above

Answer (score 0):

set below values as below
mapred.map.tasks = XX;

Choose 1 or 2 based on your hadoop version

1)
mapred.map.tasks
mapred.reduce.tasks

2)
mapreduce.job.maps
mapreduce.job.reduces